# Symbolic package not working in Octave (MATLAB's open source)

Tags: octave

I installed Octave 4.0.0 on my Windows XP system and then installed Symbolic package included with all the dependencies (win bundle). However I am getting the message "symbols undefined" at the prompt when issuing the `symbols` command. For example:

```
pkg load symbolic
symbols x = sym("x");
...
```

Comment: Try this in octave: `pkg load symbolic`

Comment: The problem is not this command "pkg load symbolic". The problem is "symbols" command. Upon issuing this command, I get the message "symbols undefined".                     For example: pkg load symbolic
symbols

x = sym("x");

f = inline("x^2*cos(x)");

ezplot(f, [-4,9])
print -deps graph.eps

[a, ierror, nfneval] = quad(f, -4, 9);

display('Area: '), disp(double(a)); Any solution to this ?

Comment: Is the package `symbolic` installed? Try `pkg install <Suitable version of symbolic>`

Comment: Please read the above issue once again. I've already stated that I have successfully installed the 'Symbolic' package and tried to issue 2 commands. First, I issued "pkg load symbolic". It succeeded without any error. Then I issued the second command "symbols" as is required. Upon issuing this second command, I got the error message including the words "symbols undefined". What do I do ? How to issue the "symbols" command successfully ? Please tell me. You can also communicate to me on this on my e-mail : mudit_mcp@yahoo.co.in

Comment: Yoi syntax is invalid. If you want to create a symbolic var x the correct syntax is "syms x" or "x = sym ('x')".

Comment: @Jens Please don't accept edits adding irrelevant tags!

Comment: @nKognito Please don't accept edits adding irrelevant tags!

Answer (score -1):

Symbolic package has been un-maintained for a long time, and doesn't work very well with latest Octave versions (it was written for a very old version of Octave). The advice usually is to switch to [maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/) which is designed exactly for that.

Comment: This is not true. The symbolic package has completely been replaced by octsympy and is well maintained. See http://octave.sourceforge.net/symbolic/NEWS.html and https://github.com/cbm755/octsympy